# Alter primary key combination for existing table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I need to add new primary key to existing table (it already contains a primary key). Please provide me the query or solution for that.
If not possible, please provide alternate solution for that.

and one more query is, is there possibility to change the existing table name (rename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in cassandra is stored by the partition key and the clustering columns within the partition key, so you cannot alter a primary key column as it would require a complete data restructuring.

Also, you cannot change a table name.

To complete the above, you must create a new table and then migrate the data to the new table.